# Why does c++ forbid implicit conversion of void*?

Tags: c++, c

In C, we can convert `void*` to any other pointers.

But C++ forbids it.

```
int *a = malloc(4);
```

leads to this error:

```
invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
```

Are there any latent dangers here in c++?

Are there any examples of c++?

Comment: C++ tries to be more type-safe than C, imho being a pain there.

Comment: Just a lot more ways to shoot your leg off in C++.  Downcasting should never be accidental.

Comment: It's just a reminder that in C++ there's always a better solution to a problem than using a `void *`.

Comment: It's also a reminder to use `new` instead of `malloc`.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of the C question. C++ has a different answer to C

Comment: @M.M False. . .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason you cannot implicitly convert from `void *` is because doing so is type unsafe and potentially dangerous. C++ tries a little harder than C in this respect to protect you, thus the difference in behavior between the two languages.

Consider the following example:

```
short s = 10; // occupies 2 bytes in memory
void *p = &s;
long *l = p;  // occupies 8 bytes in memory
printf("%ld\n", *l);
```

A C compiler accepts the above code (and prints garbage) while a C++ compiler will reject it.

By casting "through" `void *`, we lose the type information of the original data, allowing us to treat what in reality is a `short` as a `long`.

Comment: As the OP observed. He asked for why that design-decision was made.

Comment: Should not use `malloc` in C++ - User `new` instead.

Comment: @EdHeal OP was using `malloc()`, so I just decided to roll with it.

Comment: @BrianTracy - I know but try not to propagate bad behaviour. Besides should also use `sizeof(int)` and not 4

Comment: @EdHeal I totally agree. Great point about `sizeof()`. The links I provided talk about the restricted use of `malloc()` in C++.

Comment: You can't avoid malloc in C++ if you are actually writing in "Clean C": a language dialect which compiles as C and as C++. In "Clean C", you need the cast.

Comment: C++ lets you write custom allocators (overloads of the `new` operator). For getting the actual memory, there is nothing wrong with using `malloc`, rather than something like `new char[size]`.

Comment: @Kaz - Try not calling constructors. Try not able to specialise in the memory allocation strategy. Try increasing the possiblity of errors mixing `malloc` with `delete`, `new` with `free`

Comment: While we are pointing out bad practices... we should avoid C style casts too. This should use `static_cast<int*>` when converting from a `malloc`

Comment: @EdHeal Overrides of `operator new` are not supposed to call any constructors; only to provide memory. `int` objects don't have constructors; even if you use `new[]`, they stay uninited.

Comment: @Mgets There is no point in that whatsoever, because there is no risk that qualifiers will be removed and such. `(int *)` will not inappropriately choose a cast method that is more powerful than intended when the source is a `void *`.  Now if you're going from `const void *`, you have a point: the C cast will change the type and strip the qualifier.

Comment: @Kaz - What granted that overriding new just allocates memory. But does it have an avantage in safety systems whereby you can take actions in the event of lack of memory, prevent memory fragmentation etc.

Comment: It seems that C++ and C likes differnet habbits. That is all.

Comment: @Deduplicator Finally got around to answering the actual question. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the conversion in C++, but it requires a cast.  C++ aims to be a more type-safe language than C, so it tries to close some "holes in the type system" that C allows.

In C, this will be accepted without any diagnostics being required:

```
int x;
void *p = &x;
double *q = p;
*q = 0.0;
```

Type safety has been violated without any casts being present in the source code.

This is a [C++ FAQ answered by B. Stroustrup, inventor of C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-ptr).

C++ doesn't ban the conversion; it just wants it to be documented by some kind of blurb in the source code, namely a cast which at least suggests, if not proves, that it's being done on purpose.

About the origin of `void *`, [Stroustrup writes this](http://www.stroustrup.com/sibling_rivalry.pdf) (bolding mine):

> Late in its history, C with Classes<sup>*</sup> began to support the notion of a pointer to ‘‘raw memory, `void *`. The origin of `void *` is shrouded in some mystery. **I vaguely remember inventing it together with Larry
>   Rosler and Steve Johnson.** However, Dave Prosser remembers first having suggested it based on something
>   used "somewhere in Australia." Possibly both versions are correct because Dave worked closely with
>   Larry at the time. In either case, `void *` **was introduced into both languages more or less at the same time**.
>   The earliest mention of `void *` that I can find is in a memo dated January 1, 1983, about the memory management mechanisms provided by my C++ compiler, Cfront, so the origins of `void *` in C++ must go back at
>   least to mid-1982. The earliest written record of `void *`  in the context of ANSI C is a proposal by Mike Meissner dated "12 Oct 83," which presented `void *`essentially as it was accepted into ANSI C in June 1984 [Prosser,2001]

So C++ inherits the `void *` concept as Stroustrup originally envisioned it, while around the same time, the C people had a slightly different idea that was more loose in type safety.

In the case of `malloc`, of course there are dangers; but those are already flagged by the presence of the well-known identifier `malloc`; the cast doesn't bring in anything more, but not requiring it specifically for `malloc`, while requiring it everywhere else would be an awkward exception to the rules.

---

* "C with Classes" is the predecessor to C++

Answer (score 1):

In C++, if you use `malloc`, you should construct your object in the storage that `malloc` returned. If you just cast the result, your program has undefined behaviour.

```
int * a = new (malloc(sizeof(int))) int;
```

But mostly, you *shouldn't call malloc* in C++. You shouldn't have raw pointers that carry ownership of the pointed-to object.

```
auto a = std::make_unique<int>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting between void* and the fundamental types (int*, float* etc.) are more obvious.
But, because of inheritance, more unnoticeable problems will emerge.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

struct A
{
    int x;
};

struct C
{
    int y;
};

struct B : C, A
{
    int z;
    B()
    {
        x = 1;
        y = 2;
        z = 3;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B* b = new B();
    A* a = (A*)(void*)b;
    printf("%d\n", a->x);
    return 0;
}
```

the code tries to cast from B to A, it seems OK but actually not. the output is 2.
Note that multiple inheritance is not recommended in practice, but it's still legit.
if void* is used between function parameters and allow implicit casting, things will be out of control, or at least will be a mess.
void* erase the type in a unsafe way. C++ provides safe way of type erasure, i.e. std::any: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any